# Tried creating binary decision variable in place of conditional if statement in Gurobi. Getting constraint error

Tags: python, optimization, gurobi

I have followed all existing discussion posts and instructions on how to code conditional constraints in Gurobi. I cannot figure out why I am getting this error.

GurobiError: Constraint has no bool value (are you trying "lb <= expr <= ub"?)

See below code snippet from python script:

```
b = {}
gap = {}
for k in range(start_yr,end_yr):
    for i in multi_df:
        reduction[start_yr,i] = 0
        reduction[k+1,i] = 0
        for j in range(len(multi_df[i]['COMPLIANCE'])):
            for u in multi_df[i]['utilities']:
                reduction[k+1,i] += td_matrix[i,j,k]*multi_df[i]['COMPLIANCE']['CO2 reduction (Tons CO2e)'].iloc[j]*(multi_df[i]['utilities'][u]['tCO2_per_dict'][k]/multi_df[i]['utilities'][u]['tCO2_per_dict'][start_yr])
        multi_df[i]['annual_total2'] = {}
        multi_df[i]['annual_total2'][str(k)] = m.addVar(vtype=gp.GRB.CONTINUOUS, name="x")
        multi_df[i]['annual_total2'][str(k)] = multi_df[i]['annual_total'][str(k)]-sum(reduction[k,i] for k in range(start_yr,k))
        m.addConstr(multi_df[i]['annual_total2'][str(k)], gp.GRB.GREATER_EQUAL,0)
        
        b[k,i] = m.addVar(vtype=gp.GRB.BINARY, name='b')
        gap[k,i] = m.addVar(lb=0,vtype=gp.GRB.CONTINUOUS,name='gap')

        M = 15000
        
        m.addConstr(multi_df[i]['annual_total2'][str(k)] >= multi_df[i]['SQFT']*(em_fac[k]) - M*(1-count_tax[k,i]))
        m.addConstr(multi_df[i]['annual_total2'][str(k)] <= multi_df[i]['SQFT']*(em_fac[k]) + M*count_tax[k,i])

        gap[k,i] = b[k,i]*(multi_df[i]['annual_total2'][str(k)] - multi_df[i]['SQFT']*(em_fac[k]))*cost
```

I get the above error for the below lines with my 2 Big M constraints:

```
m.addConstr(multi_df[i]['annual_total2'][str(k)] >= multi_df[i]['SQFT']*(em_fac[k]) - M*(1-count_tax[k,i]))
```

I initially tried using basic if else statements but ran into gurobi errors saying I had to go this big M route.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). For debugging help, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) including the input and the full error traceback. You can [edit] the question. See [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) if you want more tips.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is very hard to read - please reformulate and post an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as suggested in the comments.

I suspect that `multi_df[i][...][...]` already contains a linear expression and is not just holding a Gurobi variable. Hence, the warning about multiple `<=` or `>=` in one constraint.